# LINQ retrieve statement didn't return latest updated result

Tags: database, vb.net, azure, linq-to-sql

I have a table called Organization and a table called Staff.

Inside the Staff table I've got 2 fields which are

- StaffStatus to indicate whether he/she is available for the organization and
- ParentStatus to inidicate whether the organization of the user is still available or not (I didn't link them due to several reasons).

I allow the owner to recover the staff (update the StaffStatus to "Available") if the ParentStatus of the staff is "Available".

There was a weird situation in my system. I first remove the staff (update StaffStatus to "Unavailable"), then I remove the organization (update staff.ParentStatus to "Unavailable"). In this condition, the owner is not allowed to recover the user. However, the ParentStatus I retrieve is "Available" (so it's still allow to recover the user), but in the database the ParentStatus is already changed to "Unavailable".

The code I used to removeUser:

```
Friend Sub removeUser(strInput As String)
    Try
        objUser = (From userDB In db.Staffs Where userDB.UserID = strInput).FirstOrDefault()
        objUser.UserStatus = "Unavailable"
        db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)
    Catch ex As Exception
        For Each occ As ObjectChangeConflict In db.ChangeConflicts
            occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges)
        Next
        db.SubmitChanges()
    End Try        
End Sub
```

The code I used to removeOrganization:

```
Friend Sub removeOrganization(strInput As String)
    Try
        objOrganization = (From organizationDB In db.Organizations
                           Where organizationDB.OrganizationID = strInput).FirstOrDefault()

        objOrganization.OrganizationStatus = "Unavailable"

        Dim objCompany = From companyDB In db.Companies
                         Where companyDB.OrganizationID = strInput

        For Each mem In objCompany
            mem.ParentStatus = "Unavailable"

            Dim objDepartment = From DepartmentDB In db.Departments
                                Where DepartmentDB.CompanyID = mem.CompanyID

            For Each record In objDepartment
                record.ParentStatus = "Unavailable"
            Next
        Next

        Dim objUser = From UserDB In db.Staffs
                      Where UserDB.OrganizationID = strInput

        For Each mem In objUser
            mem.ParentStatus = "Unavailable"
        Next

        db.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)
    Catch ex As Exception
        For Each occ As ObjectChangeConflict In db.ChangeConflicts
            occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges)
        Next
        db.SubmitChanges()
    End Try
End Sub
```

How I called the recoverUser (I used a MsgBox() to test the ParentStatus I retrieve):

```
Private Sub btnViewUserRecover_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewUserRecover.Click
    MsgBox(helperUserCKJ.getUserByID(strUserID).ParentStatus)
    If dgvUser.RowCount > 0 Then
        strUserID = dgvUser.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value
        If (helperUserCKJ.getUserByID(strUserID).ParentStatus.Equals("Unavailable")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The Organization or Company or Department of the User is unavailable now." & vbNewLine & "You need to recover the Organization or Company or Department of the User first before you can recover the User.", "User Recovery Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            Dim respond = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to recover the user?", "User Recovery Comfirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            If respond = DialogResult.Yes Then
                helperUserCKJ.recoverUser(strUserID)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The query I used to retrieve user:

```
Friend Function getUserByID(strInput As String) As Staff
    getUserByID = (From userDB In db.Staffs
                   Where userDB.UserID = strInput).FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

I can verify that the ParentStatus field in the database is already changed.

If I didn't remove the user and directly remove the organization only, then it become normal(disallow to recover user). If I remove the user and then remove the organization, when I click to recover the user, the parentStatus is "Available".

It's a weird situation. I'm using LINQ, vb.net and Microsoft Azure database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find the solution to refresh my database with the current value.

```
Friend Function getUserByID(strInput As String) As Staff
    objUser = (From userDB In db.Staffs
               Where userDB.UserID = strInput).FirstOrDefault()
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, objUser)
    getUserByID = objUser
End Function
```